# C++, вложенные классы со внешним определением

Tags: c++, классы, вложенные-классы

Я хочу сделать вложенный класс c определением вне тела объемлющего класса.

Например, так:

```
class Enclose::Inner
{
    // ...
};

class Enclose
{
    private:
    class Inner;
    Inner inner;
};
```

Компилятор сообщает мне, что `Inner inner` приводит к попытке создать объект на основе неполного типа.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать? И можно ли вообще?

Comment: нет тут никакого наследника

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, этого сделать нельзя. Именно если вы сразу же в охватывающем классе хотите объявить поле вложенного класса, то вложенный класс придется определять прямо в охватывающем классе.

Можно как-то извернуться вроде

```
class DummyBase
{
protected:
  class Inner;
};

class DummyBase::Inner
{
};

class Enclose : DummyBase
{
  Inner a;
};
```

Но стоит ли оно того - вам решать. Такой вариант определения вложенных классов (если их много) дает вам уменьшение замусоривания внешнего пространства имен, но больше фактически ничего. Ни доступа к членам `Enclose`, ни соответствующего поиска имен из `Inner` в `Enclose` вы таким способом не получаете.

Answer (score 2):

Создавать обьект, еще неопределенного класса вы не сможете, точно также, как и не сможете хранить в классе свой же экземпляр. Однако, если вы все же хотите определить класс позже, вы можете: хранить `ссыльку` или `указатель`.
Можно просто скрыть класс `Inner` в пространстве имен, и, если нужно, сделать его другом вашего класса.

Comment: Так он у него определён.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пока нет определение класса, не может быть определен вложенный в него класс.  Это может быть сделан позже, а не раньше